# Unable to connect to mongoDB "Unable to connect on first connect"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

After setting up my `mongoconfiguration`, I tried to connect to my mongodb, however an error keeps popping up, and I have not been able to set up the connection:

[image]

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [cluster0.mndwygw.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0.mndwygw.mongodb.net   
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.Onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {    
  name: 'MongoError'  
}]: did not connect
```

Here is the `index.js` file I'm using:

***index.js***

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import helmet from "helmet"
import morgan from "morgan"

// CONFIGURATIONS
dotenv.config()
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({policy: "cross-origin"}));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cors());


// MONGOOSE SETUP

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    // useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useMongoClient: true,
})
.then(async () => {
    app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));
})
.catch((error) => console.log(`${error}: did not connect`));`
```

I've checked that my `MONGO_URL` is correct (in my `.env` file)

**.ENV File:**

```
MONGO_URL ="mongodb+srv://dummyUser:<password>@cluster0.mndwygw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

*(obviously "" is not the real password)*

- I tried changing the network access of my cluster (adding different IP addresses)
- I tried removing the DNS cache of my laptop.
- I checked that I have stable network connectivity
- I checked that there aren't any restrictions or firewalls on the network I'm connected to.

What I expected to happen is that the console would log the port number as written in the code.

### Mongo Schema?

Another weird thing is that MongoDB provides me with a URL to connect to my application. The URL starts with `mongodb+srv://` but as soon as I try to make the connection, my console logs the error

> " throw new Error('Invalid mongodb uri "' + str + '". Must begin with "mongodb://"');"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg5he.png (This is a link to the error message)

Answer (score -1):

Check the version of mongoose in package.json file.

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import helmet from "helmet"
import morgan from "morgan"

// CONFIGURATIONS
dotenv.config()
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({policy: "cross-origin"}));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cors());

// MONGOOSE SETUP

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.s7f0nt6.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useUnifiedTopology: true,
    //useMongoClient: true,
})
.then(async () => {
    app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));
})
.catch((error) => console.log(`${error}: did not connect`));
```

In latest mongoose(currently I have used 7.3.2) use this **useNewUrlParser: true** not this **useMongoClient: true**. This is work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Aditya! I am also using version 7.3.2. but unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe there is something different problem